# An alternative to DOMRect in older browsers

Tags: javascript, rect

I'm teaching a guy JS and we're coding a game. To detect collision, we use DOMRect objects. Each of the two objects gives us its rectangle like this:

```
get_rect(){
    return new DOMRect (this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

In the main file we have a function to check for collision:

```
function rects_intersect(rect_a, rect_b) {
    return (rect_a.left <= rect_b.right && 
        rect_b.left <= rect_a.right &&
        rect_a.top <= rect_b.bottom &&
        rect_b.top <= rect_a.bottom);
}
```

In the game_loop each frame we call it like this:

```
if(rects_intersect(player.get_rect(), enemy.get_rect()) == true){
    alert('collision')
}
```

On my machine the code works fine. On my student's machine it doesn't work. The browser says: 'DOMRect is undefined' at the line which has:

```
return new DOMRect(this.x, this.y, this.img.width, this.img.height);
```

My student has a very old PC with Win XP on board. His Chrome is 49.0.2623.112. He says he can't update any more on XP.

Can you suggest:

1. either an alternative for DOMRect that works in earlier browsers
2. or a complete replacement for DOMRect while preserving the logic of our application

Comment: how about [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)..?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, getBoundingClientRect can only return a position and size of a standard HTML object, while in our game we create our objects from scratch

Comment: Correct so if you already have that then computing bottom or right from left+width and top+height is really nothing except if I am missing something

Comment: The goal is to make the function rects_intersect() versatile. It should take two rectangles as arguments and return true/false. If this function is dependent on the actual implementation of the objects it should check collisions for, it won't be versatile anymore and we won't be able to simply copy it from one project to another.

Comment: It would help if you would present your code in its context, probably a class?

Comment: I think the cheapest and fastest solution for me would be to create my own Rect class to store x, y, width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a polyfill to your code, which only kicks in if `DOMRect` is not already defined:

```
var DOMRect = DOMRect || function (x, y, width, height) { 
    this.x = this.left = x;
    this.y = this.top = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.bottom = y + height;
    this.right = x + width;
};
```

You should of course not have code that modifies any of the attributes. If that is the case, you should make getters & setters for these properties, so the others are kept in sync.

Comment: Can you please show how to instantiate this class now? Previously I used: new DOMRect(..., ..., ..., ...);

Comment: It is supposed to be transparent. You should not need to touch any of your existing code.